# Calling BLAKE2f with zero "rounds"

Tags: precompiled-contracts, returndata

What is the expected behavior of the BLAKE2f precompile when called with the rounds parameter set to 0?

---

Playing around on [evm.codes/playground](https://www.evm.codes/playground?fork=shanghai) I get the impression that the return data is more or less the same 64 byte string with only f and t having an impact on the value:

```
r = 0
08c9bcf367e6096a3ba7ca8485ae67bb2bf894fe72f36e3cf1361d5f3af54fa5d282e6ad7f520e511f6c3e2b8c68059b9442be0454267ce079217e1319cde05b (f = 1, t = 3)
08c9bcf367e6096a3ba7ca8485ae67bb2bf894fe72f36e3cf1361d5f3af54fa5d282e6ad7f520e511f6c3e2b8c68059b6bbd41fbabd9831f79217e1319cde05b (f = 0, t = 3)
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
08c9bcf367e6096a3ba7ca8485ae67bb2bf894fe72f36e3cf1361d5f3af54fa5d382e6ad7f520e511f6c3e2b8c68059b6bbd41fbabd9831f79217e1319cde05b (f = 0, t = 2)
                                                                 ^
08c9bcf367e6096a3ba7ca8485ae67bb2bf894fe72f36e3cf1361d5f3af54fa5d082e6ad7f520e511f6c3e2b8c68059b6bbd41fbabd9831f79217e1319cde05b (f = 0, t = 1)
                                                                 ^
08c9bcf367e6096a3ba7ca8485ae67bb2bf894fe72f36e3cf1361d5f3af54fa5d182e6ad7f520e511f6c3e2b8c68059b6bbd41fbabd9831f79217e1319cde05b (f = 0, t = 0)
                                                                 ^
```

regardless of the data (h, m, t) and the bit f. See the screenshot below ([source](https://www.evm.codes/precompiled))
[image: definitions of r, h, m, t, f] This string is the same as that output for the 4th test vector in [EIP 152](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-152)

**EDIT.** Looking at the [execution-specs](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/9aeb242ea757cdc2234beb2cf37a61aecbbf0687/src/ethereum/crypto/blake2.py#L179) the behavior makes sense: when there are zero rounds the vector v (see link) is never modified in the for loop and so when computing the ouput it XOR's the contribution of h with itself. Thus h has no impact on the output in this case. Only 't_0' and 't_1' and 'f' have an impact on the computation.